# Combining Workflows in Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to combine workflows in Apple's Automator application. Basically I saved out the automation as an application and it works like this: I can drag a folder of images onto it and it scales and renames them. At the end of the automation I would like to trigger another workflow. The issue is that the previous workflows images are taken as input to the new workflow. How can I run multiple workflows without using the output of the previous workflow as the input for the current. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of every Automator action is an **Options** button. Click it and you'll reveal a panel that includes a checkbox for **Ignore this action's input**. Check that box on the first action of your second workflow and it won't use the first workflow's output.

[image: Action Options]

Comment: I found out that you can also right-click to access this option.